# LabVIEW automatic threshold

Tags: image-processing, labview, threshold

Automatic threshold using inter-class variance is described in the NI vision help as shown in figure below. My question is what is the difference between the last two equations; they are exactly the same. what do they indicate ?

snap from the manual

[image]

Comment: i suppose you have a better chance of getting an answer in [Math stack exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: On any site, you're going to have to define the variables if you hope for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess these formulas are not correct. w(k) ususally is the class probability which cannot be the same as the total mean µ_T

Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu%27s_method

I guess they mean the same method as they both maximize the inter-class variance.